# how to show data to only visible tableview cells in ios

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Hi guys i have a custom tableview cell with a scrollview in it.the problem is all the data is getting loaded in tableview cells at once.what i want is to load the data only for the visible cells in tableView.i used [indexPath forvisiblerows]; it was in vain..cud u guys help me out below is the code.

```
-(IPadTableViewCell *)getNewCell
{
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IpadTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
{
    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[IPadTableViewCell class]])
    {
        cell= (IPadTableViewCell  *)currentObject;
        return cell;   
    }
}
return nil;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   //  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"IpadTableViewCell";
   //cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
id1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
   cell=[dicAlbumCells objectForKey:id1];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell=[self getNewCell]; 
}
cell.tag=indexPath.row;
return cell;
}

  -(void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows
  {
 NSArray *visiblePaths = [tblGallery indexPathsForVisibleRows];

for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths) {
    if (imageArray > 0) {

       [self imageButtonClicked:nil];
    }
   }
  }

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
 {        
    [self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
}
 }
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
[self loadImagesForOnscreenRows];
}
 -(void)imageButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

CGFloat prevButtonXPosition = 18, pageButtonXPosition, pageButtonWidth = 144, pageButtonHeight = 143;

for (NSInteger i =0; i<9; i++) {
    pageButtonXPosition = prevButtonXPosition ;
    prevButtonXPosition = pageButtonXPosition+pageButtonWidth+20;
    UIButton *pageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [pageButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    pageButton.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    pageButton.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    pageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    [pageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [pageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(pageButtonXPosition,0, pageButtonWidth, pageButtonHeight)];
    [pageButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pageButton setTag:i];
    [cell.scrollView addSubview:pageButton];
  }

UIButton *add=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
add.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
add.layer.borderWidth = 3;
add.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
[add addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickAdd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[add setFrame:CGRectMake(prevButtonXPosition, 0, 144, 143)];
[add setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[add setTag:0];
[cell.scrollView addSubview:add];

UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(prevButtonXPosition+35,30, 76,76)];
[iv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"last.png"]];
[cell.scrollView addSubview:iv];

[cell.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(prevButtonXPosition +165, 40)];
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.scrollView];
 }
```

Comment: isVisible seems weird. do you want to check if any of the cells are visible. you could then just do: return [[tblGallery indexPathsForVisibleRows] count] > 0, what do you want to do with this one?

Comment: sorry ....i ll post my newly written code...

Comment: what does the loadImagesForOnscreenRows method look like?

Comment: this was written to get the visible indexpath and update the corresponding rows..but doing the above method..only updates the first and last row of tableview cells

Comment: it has come to a point where it's hard to debug this without looking at the code but, do you only call imageButtonClicked to do some operations on cell. shouldn't you hear loop through all cells, see if they are visible and in that case do this operation for all of them. in any case i don't know how and where you set cell, it seems like cell is the same all the time.